# How can I make IIS6 default to .Net 2.0 when creating a new web site?

Tags: asp.net, configuration, iis-6

When I create a web site on IIS6 it defaults the ASP.NET version to 1.1. Is there a way to make the version default to 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Question already asked.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64279/how-do-you-tell-iis-6-to-set-the-net-version-to-20-not-11-when-new-sites-are-cr)

Comment: Here's more info on other things that can be scripted: http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2008/03/Scripting-an-ASPNET-installation-in-Win2k3.aspx